# jQuery validation, changing the color of seperate labels

Tags: jquery, css, validation, colors, label

I'd like to start by saying I'm new to jQuery, but not programming in general. This is killing me and I can't find the answer anywhere.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a form, and for this example I'm just going to use my two main requirements. I'm trying to input a part name and a part number. When the user doesn't enter one of them, I want to change the color of the label next to the input box, while disabling the messages portion of validate.

So, for example. When the user doesn't enter a part number, I want to change this:

```
<label for="part_name">Part Name</label>
```

To something like this:

```
<label for="part_name" style="color: #fa0008;">Part Name</label>
```

Here's my code so far. 

**HTML**

```
<div class='type_left'><label for="part_name">Part Name</label></div>
<div class='type_left'><input type="text" id="part_name" name="part_name"></div>

<div class='type_left'><label for="hj_part">hj Part Number</label></div>
<div class='type_left'><input type='text' name='hj_part'></div>
```

**jQuery** (note: This all works fine. I am running in debug mode so it doesn't try and submit.)

```
// Validate "Add Part" form ----------------
//------------------------------------------

$j('#addpartform').validate({
    debug: true,
    rules: {
        part_name: {
         required: true
        },
        hj_part: {
         required: true
        },
    },

    errorPlacement: function(error, element) { },

    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) { 
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
        if (errors) {
            alert("Hey man, you didn't enter something.")
        }           
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) { alert("works!") }

});

//------------------------------------------
// End "Add Part" form validation ----------
```

What do I need to add to my validate function to do this??

To me it sounds like it would be super simple, but I just cannot figure it out.

Thanks in advance for your help.
Dan

Answer (score 2):

Inside the if(errors), try this:

```
$('#addpartform :input').each(function(){
    if ( $(this).val() == "") ){
        $('label[for="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').css('color', '#fa0008');
    }
});
```

Essentially you are looping through the form, and if any inputs are empty,then add the color to the label with the 'for' attribute the same as the 'id'.

Comment: I was actually trying to avoid doing a loop. I settled for just using highlight and unhighlight to put a border around the input boxes.